# Can I use AJAX and JavaScript without a browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets, client-server, remote-desktop

I supposed to make a desktop application (with Java-Swing) which will remotely communicate with server(like Skype) through socket. To do that, can I use AJAX to transfer the data to the server? How can I implement the JavaScript Engine?

Are there any better ways to do this? Any advises?

Answer (score 2):

Ajax means "Making an HTTP Request without leaving the current page". As techniques go, it doesn't really seem applicable.

Rather than implementing a JavaScript engine, then writing something to make an HTTP request in JavaScript … just make the HTTP request directly from Java. You're already using that language.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, transferring each piece of data makes me to think in Ajax. By using HTTP request in Java, won't that be a bandwidth problem, which exited in browser based environment?

Comment: An HTTP request / response pair aren't going to shrink just because you put a web browser in the way. Just make sure you use a decent HTTP library (with caching and gzip support).